# Unable to connect Google App Engine and Cloud SQL using Flask and SQL Alchemy

Tags: google-app-engine, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, google-cloud-sql

I'm attempting to connect a Flask App Engine instance to a Cloud SQL instance and the connection works when I run things locally but doesn't work when I deploy it using `gcloud app deploy`. I'm using `flask_sqlalchemy` to connect to the database with the following URI string

`app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"]= f"postgresql://postgres:{PASSWORD}@{PUBLIC_IP_ADDRESS}:5432/{DBNAME}"`

However this results in a timeout error that looks like this:

`OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) could not connect to server: Connection timed out`

Comment: Connect your service to your Cloud SQL instance's Unix domain socket at the following path: `/cloudsql/INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME` and not with the IP:PORT.

Answer (score 1):

Try taking a look at these pages:

[Connecting from App Engine standard environment to Cloud SQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-app-engine-standard)
[Connecting from App Engine flexible environment to Cloud SQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-app-engine-flexible)

There are instructions for both Private and Public IP.

You may be also interesting this demo app:
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/master/cloud-sql/postgres/sqlalchemy